# How to share multiple urls to Facebook on iOS 6

Tags: ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

Hi I'm using the facebook share sheet on SDK 3.1 and it works except when I try to share 2 urls it crashes.

```
NSArray* urls = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://google.com", @"http://yahoo.com", nil];
BOOL displayedNativeDialog = [FBNativeDialogs presentShareDialogModallyFrom:self
                                                   initialText: @"hellooo"
                                                        images: nil
                                                          urls: urls
                                                       handler:     ^(FBNativeDialogResult result, NSError *error) {
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"handler error:%@, %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
if (result == FBNativeDialogResultSucceeded)
{
    NSLog(@"handler success");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"handler user cancel");
}
}
}];
```

Result:

-[__NSCFConstantString isMusicStoreURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3d23e8

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString isMusicStoreURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3d23e8'

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the NSArray of Urls it is taking is expecting NSURLs, not NSStrings. You can use the static URLWithString to get the NSURLs for the array.

Comment: Thanks I made that change and it causes it not to crash anymore but the Facebook post only shows 1 url.